# JQTouch support for IPhone

Tags: iphone, multi-touch

I am building a website which provides support on Iphone also. I am using JQTouch jquery library(www.jqtouch.com) which provides multi-touch functionality like swipe, flip, back page.
It would be great to hear from you guys on how to extend zoom-in and zoom-out functionality for photos. Does JQTouch provide any readymade function for the same. Also I would like to hear more on the touch screen functionality that I could use more in my application.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The JQTouch library specifically disables resizing the viewport, so you would not be able to use this for zooming in on photos. See this post which talks about performance, but also mentions that they disable the viewport resizing: http://blog.jqtouch.com/post/205113875/milliseconds-responsiveness-and-the-fast-tap

Answer (score 0):

Normally this effect is achieved by using css techniques or a plugin like [this](http://www.dio5.com/plugins/jquery.magnifier/index.html).

You show a small version of an image and on mouse over and move, show a portion of a blown up version.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good jQTouch extension and demo for pinch, zoom, rotate and very flexible too: http://www.reddit.com/r/iphone/comments/bhkx3/jqtouch_gestures_extension_multitouch_events_and/

Basically you get to combine these events however you want.